# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Report generation requires csv output format

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I'm getting the following error when I try to run a JMeter load test in non-GUI mode with output file format as XML. I am using a docker container for installing the JMeter.
I need the request and response data to be part of the result-jtl file

Error:

```
2020-11-04 08:44:35,820 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Error in NonGUIDriver
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Report generation requires csv output format, check 'jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format' property
        at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.<init>(ReportGenerator.java:123) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.runNonGui(JMeter.java:1062) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.startNonGui(JMeter.java:994) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:566) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:252) [ApacheJMeter.jar:5.3]
2020-11-04 08:44:35,825 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: An error occurred:
org.apache.jmeter.report.config.ConfigurationException: Error in NonGUIDriver Report generation requires csv output format, check 'jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format' property
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.runNonGui(JMeter.java:1104) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.startNonGui(JMeter.java:994) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:566) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:252) [ApacheJMeter.jar:5.3]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Report generation requires csv output format, check 'jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format' property
        at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.<init>(ReportGenerator.java:123) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.runNonGui(JMeter.java:1062) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
        ... 7 more
```

Jmeter Arguments:

`-Dlog_level.jmeter=DEBUG -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true -Jjmeterengine.force.system.exit=true -n -t test/trivial/test-plan.jmx -l test/trivial/test-plan.jtl -j test/trivial/jmeter.log -e -o test/trivial/report`

Comment: Did my answer help? do you need clarification?

Comment: @user7294900 thanks for your reply...I had taken a different route and abandoned this setup...That is why it took some time for me to reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate dashboard report (-e -o) you need to have CSV  results as exception state

> Report generation requires csv output format

So either change to CSV or generate dashboard report later using jtl file

> generate the HTML report using menu item **Tools → Generate HTML report**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml`

you will have to remove this property, as of [JMeter 5.3](http://-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml) HTML Reporting Dashboard can be generated only out of .jtl files in CSV format as per [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html):

> The dashboard generator is a modular extension of JMeter. Its default behavior is to read and process samples **from CSV files** to generate HTML files containing graph views. It can generate the report at end of a load test or on demand.

If you need to additionally store request/response data you can use [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) or [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/) listener

Answer (score 0):

I did observe the similar exception. Please find the solution in steps :

1. Open the user.properties file. You might have the value
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
2. Change it to
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv

You can generate the csv file and Output folder by below steps :

1.Open Terminal

2.Navigate to bin folder of Jmeter

> sh jmeter.sh -n -t your_JMX_File.jmx -l your_output_csv_file.csv -e -o
> yourTargetedOutputFolder